# Oscilloscope probe points

Tags: pcb, rf, test

The answer to another question identified two PCB-mounted scope probe "holders":

[image]
[image]

I can't find these at any distributor's web site because I don't what they are called. Can someone, please, give me the nomenclature I need to purchase these items?

Comment: it is a test point .... did you try to google the number that is printed next to it?

Comment: Good tip, thanks, I didn't realize that was the Tek p/n. Naturally, there is a different set for each probe diameter, and there are many different probe diameters. I'm going with the "ground spring" approach as it's the more flexible per dollar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's made by Tektronix and should be bought with the central hole part too: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Wow - pricey!

Comment: [Try this](https://www.ebay.co.uk/i/323408559288?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=710-134428-41853-0&mkcid=2&itemid=323408559288&targetid=877696481749&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=1007103&poi=&campaignid=9441192132&mkgroupid=102652505024&rlsatarget=pla-877696481749&abcId=578896&merchantid=9642454&gclid=CjwKCAjwpqv0BRABEiwA-TySwbDf7vxpgIYSj9XyxIqPJ7PNmlgK9qvF8cFB5p_IbKcZzjAh2gBX3xoC6U4QAvD_BwE). Or [this](https://www.keysight.com/en/pd-1000003843%3Aepsg%3Apro-pn-N2768A/vertical-mini-probe-socket-quantity-25?cc=US&lc=eng). Search "oscilloscope probe PCB sockets".

Comment: I marked this as answered with the caveat that the actual p/n, as pointed out by jsotola, is 131-4244-00.

Comment: @BrianK1LI I'm looking to see where that was pointed out - might he have deleted his comment or am I being thick?

Comment: Oh, it's written on the PCB!!

Answer (score 1):

The coiled device is called a "probe tip ground spring" or some variation on that phrase. Not quite as good as the "socket" device, but sufficient to my purpose.

They are available relatively cheaply compared to the "socket" device from main-line distributors and from auction sites. Be sure to get the spring that fits your probe.

Note the different offsets between the probe tip and the point of ground contact.

[image]